# How to restrict gutenberg block next post & previous post to same category?

Tags: block-editor

I am using gutenberg default blocks [next post], [previous post] in the template.

[image]

but,

How to restrict the post navigation to the same category ?

In gutenberg editor, it don’t have the parameters to set to restrict post navigation to the same category.

So, how can I solve it perfectly ?

Do you know, friends?

Thanks very much.